# Create SQLite database in Maven cross platform

Tags: sqlite, maven, jdbc

My client has an SQL file that needs to be processed and turned into an SQLite database during the Maven build process. It seemed simple enough: just use the `org.codehaus.mojo.sql-maven-plugin` with the `org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc` JDBC driver. Unfortunately, version 3.7.2 of the driver has a trivial oversight of a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/issues/detail?id=3) that nonetheless prevents it from being used in this situation. Although it's supposedly been fixed months ago, it's not available in the central Maven repository and no one will answer my queries. Other posts indicate that later versions will remove pure Java support altogether.

So how am I supposed to create an SQLite database from within Maven?

Comment: Garret, was at least the ant task updated with the fix? If it was, invoking ant from maven would be an option.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. I haven't tried the fix because I'm still looking for it in Maven. If the bug was fixed, then it would work as an `sql-maven-plugin` and I wouldn't need an Ant task. Maybe I'm not understanding your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion meant to use maven's ability to run ant targets as part of the build. It's a real helper to use build logic implemented for ant but not (yet) for maven. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/ So, if the fix has made it into ant task, it can be available for your maven build with little effort.

Comment: Can you post your pom?

Comment: This was years ago in a project for a client I'm no longer working for. I have no idea of the status of this. Unfortunately I'm too busy on other things to try to reconstruct the POM. But it would be nice to know if the bug fix I mentioned was ever included in a published update on Maven Central.

Comment: Just guessing from looking at my post, it would appear that there is a [version 3.21.0](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.xerial%7Csqlite-jdbc%7C3.21.0.1%7Cjar) available on Maven Central. See https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.xerial%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sqlite-jdbc%22 . So I would guess maybe the bug fix is available now. Hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

I ran also into this problem and finally I found a good solution: 
set `escapeProcessing` tag to `false` as in the following example:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>create-schema</id>
    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
        <escapeProcessing>false</escapeProcessing>
        <srcFiles>
            <srcFile>src/main/sql/your-schema.sql</srcFile>
        </srcFiles>
     </configuration>
</execution>
```